# MongoDB.Bson not appearing in VS Intellisense

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I install `MongoDB.Driver` from Nuget Packages in VS it installs as expected, but when I try to use `MongoDB.Bson` in a class it says "The type or namespace name 'Bson' does not exist in the namesppace 'MongoDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

[image: Image of my Code]

Answer (score 0):

To have the solution reference external libraries, place the library files, and all required dependencies, into a “\Plugins” folder in your project. You can get these from NuGet and unpack them. Unity will then add the references to your solution. This isn’t guaranteed, as the library might reference other libraries that are simply incompatible with Unity, but this is the process in general.